# How to set Boolean = True unique per model with Fk

Tags: django, django-models

How can I save Place model with only one unique True? so if I user have 10 program and only 1 can be is active=True?
so if I update some to True , that Program which has True became False this User. I need `def save`?

My models:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name="program")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting save is useful here indeed. Something like this should work.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if self.is_active:
        Program.objects.filter(user=self.user).update(is_active=False)
    
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: but it will update for all users, i need just for one.

Comment: Ah, I edited it now to only disable all the programs for the current user. The save will then reactivate the current program, so that exactly one is active.